# Addressing a API directly with a POST for SweetCaptcha

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Thanks in advance.

I am attempting to use SweetCaptcha ( A captcha alternative) and address their API directly without using one of their SDK's (Cant use PHP or Node.JS).

Ideally the returned HTML would go inside a div within the form tag when the page loads (I am new... so I might be wording that incorrectly.)

I used POSTMAN to test my api call, and it worked great. Yet, I struggle with how to do the post and display the results.   I have tried several Jquery/Ajax examples but none seem to fit what I am doing (since they rely on a form) or even work when I click the example button.

Here is one example I used that included the API address and parameters:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#driver").click(function(event){
              $.post( 
              "http://sweetcaptcha.com/api",
               { method: "get_html", app_id: "xxxx", app_key:   "xxxxxxx", platform: "api" },
         function(data) {
            $('#stage').append(data);
         }

         );
     });
  });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
     <div id="stage" style="background-color:blue;">
      STAGE1
       </div>
    <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
   </body>
 </html>
```

ANy help would be appreciated!!
Ref: http://sweetcaptcha.com/downloads#api

Comment: I am also trying to integrate this with API, I also used 'POSTMAN' but I couldn't make it. Could you give few instructions about this??

Comment: As the accepted answer explains below, you need to use one of the server side SDK's.

Comment: Thank you, I got your answer.

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all anymore: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/sweetcaptcha-service-used-to-distribute-adware.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do a request to the SweetCaptcha API directly from your client-side code (e.g. HTML page). You may argue it is possible technically, but in fact your captcha check becomes useless: anyone can simply skip that check. Moreover you are sharing your app id and secret with everyone in the world by embedding those values into your page and that is really not a good idea.

So anyway your need some server-side code. Which technology your use for your website? There are JS, PHP and .NET SDKs for the moment.